# My 9 month old bearded dragon poops only every week or two

Tags: health, diet, defecation, bearded-dragon

I know baby bearded dragons are supposed to poop multiple times a day, but mine only poops every 7-14 days. He always eats his bugs (BSFL) and vegetables (Kale), but I am concerned that he is unhealthy. I make sure he doesn't swallow more than 1 bug at a time and his poop is very wet and doesn't have any solid things in it. Is he ok or should I do something?

Comment: can someone please answer this